# Java client server code

Tags: java, client

Can you help me to check whether the logic of my ack server and ack client is correct or not? The client keeps sending ack to a server and when the server receives an ack, it generates a timestamp. I find the measured time when client and server are on one machine is very different from client and server are on two machine. For example, on one machine, the measured time is several milisec, but, on two machines, the measured time is hundreds of milisec. I measured each operation which can not exceed 1 ms. So I guess maybe the ack server and client side are not correct. Thanks.

Comment: You should expect different results on remote machines and your local machine. However, hundreds of millis sounds too much - where are the two machines located?

Comment: What two times are you comparing? I see the System.getNanotime in the server's processAck, which sets your "receive time", but where are you getting (and more importantly, setting) your "send time"?  If it's in the client, you've probably run into the "two clocks" problem.

Comment: The "send time" is set in another thread located in the same machine as ack server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, but are you taking network latency into account? It would be helpful if you could give us an example of output you've seen compared with what you would expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

The RTCs of two systems can be out. Possibly you are experiencing due to this....

Even if the times sync automatically latency issues will almost always cause two different systems to be slightly out of sync.